# Cannot create any sudo users

Tags: sudo

I'm new to linux. I have installed ubuntu desktop 22.04.1 and am trying to install crossover. You do this using sudo but the only ubuntu user is not a sudoer. I googled to see how you add a person to the sudoers list but apparently you do this with visudo and again the only user does not have the right privileges. That seems to leave me in a catch-22. Can anyone help me get out?

Comment: Also, you won't need to change anything in `sudoers` file (using `visudo`) to have a `sudo` user. Default is that there is a group called `sudo`, and you only need to add a user to this group.

Comment: @guiverc OK I've added some detail on that (desktop, 22.04.1). It did set up a single user, lm. When I go into terminal I see `@lm`. If I then try to run the sudo command I get an error message telling me that lm is not a sudoer. For some reason the username appears in capitals in settings but there is only one name in the list so I think it must be the same user that appears in lower case in terminal.

Comment: no, character-cases (Upper/Lower) matter.

Comment: @αғsнιη If I try to change to LM in terminal (I typed su LM) I get an error message to the effect that there is no such user or the user entry is not complete.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l` and `id` to the question, please.